# Flutter_foreground_task: how to "attach" to a running task when I restart my app?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm using [flutter foreground task](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task) plugin in my app.

Here is my usage of the lib:

- I start my app, which starts a foreground task.
- I close my app with "close all" on android: all apps are closed.
- The foreground task continues, and that is expected: great.
- When I start again the application (not from the notification: from its icon launcher (on android), I would like to detect the foreground_task is already running, and to attach to its receivePort BUT:

  - when I start, await FlutterForegroundTask.isRunningService returns false
  - Even if I init the task before.

=> How can I do to know a foreground task is running when I start my app?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When an app is restarted, the `SendPort` variable sent is different from the initial one, so you need to create a global `SendPort? _sendPort` in the `TaskHandler` class, then initialize it in the `onStart()` method. In the `onRepeatEvent()` method check if the member `SendPort _sendPort` is the same with the `SendPort sendPort` parameter provided by the `onRepeatEvent()` handler, if not, just replace it, that's all. You will get connected to the main isolate's `ReceivePort` as usual. Short Example:

```dart
class ForgroundTask extends TaskHandler {
SendPort? _sendPort;
// ...
// initialise the send port on start
 @override
  Future<void> onStart(DateTime timestamp, SendPort? sendPort) async {
    _sendPort = sendPort;
   // ..
}
@override
  Future<void> onRepeatEvent(DateTime timestamp, SendPort? sendPort) async {
      // replace with the new send port when there is not match in comparison
      if (_sendPort != sendPort) {
        _sendPort = sendPort;
      }
      // ..
}
```